# Convert Tensorflow strings.split output to an Int

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, casting, byte

I have a Tensorflow dataset containing image names.

A part of that name is the key to a separate Python dict. I therefore need to split the image name as below in my sample code, and cast the resulting byte string to an int for my Python dict. However, I cannot cast to the required integer.

I have tried using int.from_bytes() with both byteorder='little' and 'big', and also signed = 'True' and 'False' but I am getting an incorrect integer.

I presume this is a simple task and I am missing something very basic? How do I complete this? What data type will numpy() return?

```
 example_img_name = b'78886804_20140704_0506.tif'
 img_name_parts = tf.strings.split(example_img_name, '_')
 a_id = img_name_parts[0]
 byte_id = a_id.numpy()

 print(int.from_bytes(byte_id, byteorder='big', signed=True))
```

The above code prints the integer 3978992084860809268

The desired outcome is the integer 78886804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a_id` is a tensor of UTF-8 string bytes, not integer bytes. That's why you keep getting the wrong integer.

Use python decode() and encode() to translate between string bytes and python strings.

In your case, to get the string version of byte_id, do `byte_id.decode()`